# Creating a scrollable table with horizontal and vertical scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a wide table, and I want to create the table with both horizontal and vertical scrollbar, and the table could have a fixed header on top

the horizontal one need to scroll the column with the header at the same time
the vertical one should appear all the time

I tried using css overflow, but most example just give me vertical scroll with fixed header, no horizontal one

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
position:fixed;
```

in the css class of your header . The header will remain still when you make a scroll.

Not sure whether this is what you expect.

Comment: thanks, I tried using overflow, it works either horizontally or vertically, but not in both